# Adding a module to an existing library

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I recently installed a [library](https://tenpy.github.io/index.html), which created a directory and subdirectories containing various python3 scripts.

Lets focus on the directory

```
/Users/username/TeNPy/tenpy/models
```

This contains some pre-made modules, for instance one called toric_code.py, containing the class 'ToricCode'.

If I run a script (lets call it test.py, situated on my desktop, for instance) that *only* contains

```
from tenpy.models.toric_code import ToricCode
```

this works perfectly fine, I get not errors.

Now I created a new script, called it test_module.py and copy-pasted the toric_code.py script. The content between the two is *precisely the same*. Now I put test_module.py in the same directory as toric_code.py.

If I run

```
from tenpy.models.test_module import ToricCode
```

I get the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tenpy.models.test_module'
```

TL;DR - How can I make a library I installed read one of my own scripts as a module?.

Comment: Are you sure that you edited the correct directory? When I do the same process on my machine, it works as it should. If you do `import sys; print(sys.path)`, does it include `/Users/username`?

Comment: Actually -- considering that you said the name of the folder is `teNPy` with that capitalization, it's almost certainly not loading the library from that folder -- Python's library loading is case-sensitive, IIRC.

Comment: How can you make a library read your own scripts? It is already written, it is not aware of your script even if you put it in the same directory...

Comment: What do you mean “If I run”? Please expand in the question. What script are you running with that import that fails? Where is the script situated?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I updated the question. The script test.py only contains 'from tenpy.models.toric_code import ToricCode' and I've placed it on my desktop. This works fine. If I change it to 'from tenpy.models.test_module import ToricCode' then I get an error about the non-existence of the module.

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you are running this code from. Providing a directory structure would help.

It looks like the issue is that the folder you seek to export your classes from is not in the PYTHONPATH. If you ever want to look at what is in the PYTHONPATH, you could use:

```
import sys

print(sys.path)
```

You could add that at the top of your code to debug it in terms of modules and see what your PYTHONPATH looks like.

You need to add a file (usually empty, but not always) called `__init__.py` in the folder you want to import code from.

Here is a great guide to understanding how importing modules work:

[Definite Guide To Python Imports](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html)

Alternatively, you could also add the following code to the top of your code:

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.pardir, os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), os.pardir, os.pardir))
```

If you were to add the code above, you won't have to do something like:

```
from <folder>.file import <class/method>
```

but you could just use:

```
from file import <class/method>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've noticed that if I just change the name of one of the ready-made modules, and type